# Элемент массива на первое место переместить

Tags: javascript, jquery

есть массив сообщений

```
dialogs(
  {id:1,message:'message',avatar:'img.png'},
  {id:2,message:'message2',avatar:'img2.png'},
  {id:3,message:'message3',avatar:'img3.png'},
)
```

Как переместить строку массива с id=2 на первую позицию в массиве?

Comment: А что делать с той строкой, что была там раньше?

Comment: вопрос - зачем перемещать строку на первую? именно весь объект или то, что в `message`?

Comment: нет, всю строку, по принципу как  в вк, когда пришло новое сообщение, то этот диалог перемещаем на самый верх

Comment: а то что была на первом месте сместить вниз

Comment: массив то где? у вас тут вроде вызов функции с тремя параметрами.

Comment: это я так массив написал 3 тремя строками

Comment: `[ dialogs[0], dialogs[1] ] = [ dialogs[1], dialogs[0] ];` — их можно просто поменять местами) Ну или `dialogs.unshift( dialogs.splice(1, 1)[0] );`

Answer (score 1):

```js
const f = id => {
  const d = [{
      id: 1,
      message: "message",
      avatar: "img.png"
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      message: "message2",
      avatar: "img2.png"
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      message: "message3",
      avatar: "img3.png"
    }
  ];
  return [d.find(el => el.id === id)].concat(d.filter(el => el.id != id))
};
console.log(f(2));
```